# Handling superfluous or duplicative parameters for functions?

Tags: python

I have a question on what is good practice for dealing with situations where parameters passed to a function may be duplicative/superfluous. Let's say I have a simple function to assess whether any user is over a limit of 0.5; and that this function can take a pd.Series or an array-like as input:

```
import pandas as pd

def validate_user_holdings(user_holdings, **kwargs):

    user_names = kwargs.get('user_names', None)

    if isinstance(user_holdings, pd.Series):
        errors = ['{} over limit'.format(user_name)
                 for user_name in user_holdings.index
                 if user_holdings[user_name] > 0.5]

    else:
        errors = ['{} over limit'.format(user_name)
                 for i, user_name in enumerate(user_names)
                 if user_holdings[i] > 0.5]
    return errors
```

If we then create some dummy data and pass it as a pair of lists, then all is well - let's call this Scenario A:

```
user_holdings = [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.6]
user_names = ['User A','User B','User C','User D']
# Using a list for user_holdings and a separate list to supply user_names
validate_user_holdings(user_holdings, user_names = user_names)
```

gives me the correct result:

```
['User D over limit']
```

(Scenario B) I get the same result if I create a series from these two lists and pass that:

```
user_holdings_series = pd.Series(index=user_names, data=user_holdings)
# Putting both lists into a series and passing that
validate_user_holdings(user_holdings_series)
```

In the next two scenarios we start to enter the moral maze:

(Scenario C) If I pass the series but also pass user_names, user_names is not used but also doesn't conflict with the series, so no real harm done:

```
validate_user_holdings(user_holdings_series, user_names = user_names)
```

Where things start to get nasty is if the user is passing a conflicting list via the user_names parameter, while also passing a pd.Series:

```
user_names = ['User D','User C','User B','User A']
validate_user_holdings(user_holdings_series, user_names = user_names)
```

The error here is the same as the other scenarios:

```
['User D over limit']
```

But obviously there is now a risk of the user being confused about which user is actually overweight.

Is there a generally accepted Pythonic good practice to deal with these situations? Should I, say,

i) warn if there is superfluous user input but it does not conflict?

ii) error if there is a superfluous user input and it does conflict (so the user_names list disagrees with the pd.Series.index in this case)?

iii) allow explicitly passed user input (the user_names list in Scenario D) to overwrite the pd.Series.index?
Or something else entirely?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Just put this text in the docstring: _"If user_names is passed, it overrides the the user names from the user_holdings"_. And yes, I would make the data in `user_names` _stronger_, because it is more explicitly setting the names. I would also replace `**kwargs` with `user_names=None`.

Comment: I'd 1) add a "strict" switch defaulting to True that controls whether redundant/conflictiing user_names.raise or are ignored - I would not do a potentially expensive consistency check. If there is a use case I'd 2) add an "update_user_names" keyword allowing a user who knows what they arer doing to override the index.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - it feels like overall there's no consensus on what's best practice here, so I think I'll skip the upcheck and just warn if superfluous parameters are being provided.